# If your theme is to capture the colors of the fall, what would you advise a photographer to have in mind?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, technique, landscape, autumn

If your theme is to **capture the colors of the fall**, what would you advise a photographer to have in mind? And to make it more specific, the photographer asking for your advice is beginner-to-intermediate when it comes to **landscape** photography.

Having this specific scenario in mind:

1. What **gear** would you make sure not to forget?
2. What **time of day** is most appropriate and why?
3. What **light** are looking for to emphasize the amazing bright autumn colours?
4. How much can the **vantage point** influence the results?
5. Any **techniques** specific to landscape photography to improve the autumn shot?
6. Any particularities to be aware of if the **location** is in Ontario, Canada?

This might seem like a landscape photography primer, but links to useful an well put together articles, or exemplary bodies of work would also be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tip list

- Use circular polarizers
- The "golden hour" at sunset and sunrise are typically the best
- Don't be afraid to shoot mid day, the sky can be blue and contrasts well with the bright colors
- Get up close to the trees, underneath or even on them for perspective
- Wide angle lenses are a must, but telephoto lenses offer a nice secondary option
- Most of Ontario, Canada probably peaks early in September for color
- Macro lenses are great to get down and shoot the decay at ground level
- Tripod
- Cable release(or self timer if you wish)

Considering that you are in Ontario, CA - I would think you could even get the opportunity to get some great fall leaves with snow shots. These are favorites of mine, water/ice on a stream together with red/orange leaves and white snow - AWESOME!

Comment: Add to this list: Bring a tripod and cable (remote) release and some waterproofing -- even plastic bags. Bring rags to wipe down wet, dirty or muddy stuff if you decide to wade into a stream. Look for water reflections. Shoot a lot!

Answer (score 1):

#### A few quick ideas / hints

Shoot Details

- a single leaf
- detail of bark
- leaves on a wet rock
- a drop of water on the end of a leaf

Justapose - put something surprising in the scene

- how about an autumn-coloured car?

People

- Placing one or more people in your scene can add a sense of scale
- It can add a centre of interest, drawing the eye to a face

Typical Landscape Suggestions

- Include a foreground, middle ground and background
- Don't be afraid of long exposures - they can do nice things with those trees